# vglm: Error in vglm.fitter, due to matrix dimension?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution

I've looked to other Error in **vglm.fitter**-related posts but they don't seem (or I cannot) related to this one.

This the error I get when running vglm for multinomial regression (classification):

```
R: fit.tracks.vglm = vglm(formula = class ~ ., data = train.data[c(-1)], family = multinomial())
Error in vglm.fitter(x = x, y = y, w = w, offset = offset, Xm2 = Xm2,  : 
  17115 parameters but only 14697 observations
```

My train.data dimension is 4899 x 5706 including 5704 "X.." variables, see below:

```
R: train.data[1:3,1:10]
  col1      class X2 X6 X7 X17 X18 X25 X33 X37
1 220351 class1  0  0  0   0   1   0   0   0
2  30981 class1  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
3 154632 class1  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The matrix is very sparse (0.3% of non zero elements, but each variable has at least 10 non zero elements). The `class` column has 4 categories, thus I understand that 5705*3 = 17115 and 4899*3 = 14697.

Is it simply because there are ***too much*** variables ? is there a threshold ?, ratio rule of the thumb e.g. nrows/nvars, to follow ? ...

Several hours later after post: I've run a successful test with 2000 variables ... seems to be a max limit  on variables number issue ...?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the reason while reading the introduction of this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20077255): "*... logistic regression models for a high-dimensional data set, ... is impossible by a single logistic regression model due to the restriction that the sample size needs to be larger than the number of predictors*"